# How to replace 'NA' based on values that come before and after

Tags: r, dataset, dataframe

I am reading in a .csv with a column that contain series of matching number between which are NAs. I want to replace the NAs with the numbers on the outside of the series so as to make long series of matching numbers.

I want to turn this:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,NA,NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA,NA,3))
#into this
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,3,3,3,3))
```

I have tried to find a way to do this, but all my searches have left me helpless.

I am still relatively new to R, so if you need any more information let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the `NA` (after the last `2`) of `df2$col1` can you explain ?

Comment: @dickoa  I believe it's because that `NA` is bounded by non-matching values.

Comment: @all, thanks guys. What vision! Note: the NA after the last two was implying that I'd want that to remain an unimportant value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)

a0 <- na.locf(df$col1)
a1 <- na.approx(df$col1)

df2 <- transform(df, col1 = ifelse(a0 == a1, a0, NA))
```

which gives:

```
> df2
   col1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    2
11    2
12   NA
13    3
14    3
15    3
16    3
```

*REVISED:*  Made some improvements.

Comment: This looks like the cleanest solution +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `na.approx` in the zoo package to give you a linear interpolation:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,NA,NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA,NA,3))
require(zoo)
outVec = na.approx(df$col, na.rm=F)
```

As mentioned in the comments by RoyalTS that would replace the NA between the 2 and 3 with 2.5.

If you don't want the interpolation and know that the number is non-overlapping (e.g. no c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA,2) ) you can do a `foreach` loop:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,NA,NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA,NA,3))
tt=unique(df$col1); tt=tt[!is.na(tt)]
require(foreach)
foreach(num = tt) %do%
{ df$col1[min(which(df$col1==num)):max(which(df$col1==num))] = num  }
print(df)
```

Comment: But that would replace the `NA` between the `2` and `3` with `2.5`, no?

Comment: That is correct - I altered the code change that, thanks for the spot.

Comment: The way you added the `NA` back in assumes that it's supposed to be `NA` because it there is only one `NA` between the 2 and the 3.  It seems to me that the reason for the `NA` is because 2 is not equal to 3, though I guess the OP would need to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

`rle` to the rescue again.

```
Rgames> foo<-unlist(df)
Rgames> foo[is.na(foo)]<- -1 # I'm assuming you have no "-1" in your data. Pick a nonvalid number
Rgames> bar<-rle(foo)
Rgames> for(j in 2:9) if(bar$values[j-1]==bar$values[j+1]&bar$values[j-1]!=-1) bar$values[j]<-bar$values[j-1]
Rgames> oof<-inverse.rle(bar)
Rgames> oof
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2 -1  3  3  3  3
```

Then if desired replace all `-1` with `NA` .

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to `rle`. Good stuff +1